# Returning A List Of Lists In a Recursive Function

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion

I am trying to solve a problem I found on Leetcode, I need to compute all the combinations for length *r* for a given set of characters. I managed to nail down the algorithm, well, almost.

I am having a hard time getting my recursive function to return the output in the form of a list of lists.

Here's the function.

chrs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

```
# MY CODE TO PRODUCE SUCH COMBINATIONS
def combination(combn, r, chrset):

    if len(combn)==r:
            return combn

    res = []

    if r - len(combn) <= len(chrset):  # A KIND OF OPTIMIZATION TO CUT DOWN IF WE KNOW FOR SURE THE FINAL LENGTH CAN NEVER BE = R

        for idx,chr in enumerate(chrset):
            combn+=chr
            res += combination(combn, r, chrset[idx+1:])
            combn=combn[:len(combn)-1]
    return [res]

r=5
idx=0
result = combination('', r, chrs)
print("MY CODE")
print(result)
```

Here's the output

```
MY CODE
[[[[[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F'], []], [['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], []], [], []], [[['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], []], [], []], [], [], []], [[[['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], []], [], []], [], [], []], [], [], [], []]]
```

What I'd like is for this to be the output

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']]
```

I have tried several combinations but somehow it always ends up being a nested list (some of the combinations is always a list within a list within a list within a list...)

I do not want to process such outputs outside my function but rather understand some effective technique to ensure recursion does not lead to such patterns.

EDIT

I understand the question may have been asked in another way by other users and I'm aware of workarounds to get this to work, once such workaround being using shallow copy combn[:].
I would like to avoid this since it is an expensive operation (in terms of space and I guess time as well).

```
def combination(combn, r, chrset, final_result):

    if len(combn)==r:
            final_result.append(combn[:])
            return final_result
    if r - len(combn) <= len(chrset):  # A KIND OF OPTIMIZATION TO CUT DOWN IF WE KNOW FOR SURE THE FINAL LENGTH CAN NEVER BE = R

        for idx, chr in enumerate(chrset):
            combn.append(chr)
            combination(combn, r, chrset[idx + 1:], final_result)
            combn.pop()

    return final_result

r=5
idx=0
result = combination([], r, chrs, [])
print("MY CODE")
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could consider not using enumerate and using a separate helper function that implements [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking):

```
def helper(start, chrs, r, comb, combinations):
    if len(comb) == r:
        combinations.append(comb.copy())
    for i in range(start, len(chrs)):
        comb.append(chrs[i])
        helper(i + 1, chrs, r, comb, combinations)
        comb.pop()
    
def get_combinations(chrs, r):
    combinations = []
    helper(0, chrs, r, [], combinations)
    return combinations

chrs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
r = 5
combinations = get_combinations(chrs, r)
print(combinations)
```

**Output:**

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']]
```

Comment: The usage of copy(), this is what I was hoping to avoid, preferably an elegant way to backtrack and only add those valid combinations to a data structure. I tried several but it looks like this is the only way since you recommended usage of copy() as well :) Thanks